# Convergence of derivative-like limits to derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f: [0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable. I want to show that the following limit equals $0$ for any $c>0, u\in [-c, 1]$:
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f\left(h(c+u)\right) - f(ch)}{h^2} - \frac{uf'(ch)}{h} - \frac{1}{2}u^2f''(ch).$$

The last term can easily seen to be $-\frac{1}{2}u^2f''(0^+),$ but I'm not sure how to show that the the first two terms together equal $\frac{1}{2}u^2f''(0^+).$ The first term does look somewhat like a derivative, but not quite. I rewrote the first two terms together to:
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{h}\left(f(h(c+u)) - f(ch)\right) - uf'(ch)}{h}$$
I then tried using L'Hôpital, but that only seems to complicate the limit more and more with each successive application.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated.